# Using regular expressions to modify a string

Tags: python, regex

How can I use regular expressions to change this string

```
':: 1:62 2:31 :: 3:4 4:32'
```

to:

```
':: 1:62.0 2:31.0 :: 3:4.0 4:32.0'
```

Is there any clean way to do it without using `re.split`?

Comment: You know that the question goes in the question box, right?

Comment: Are you doing this because you want the numbers to be cast to floats later? There might be a neater solution if it's your code that's doing the casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> re.sub("([0-9]+:[0-9]+)", "\\1.0", ':: 1:62 2:31 :: 3:4 4:32')
':: 1:62.0 2:31.0 :: 3:4.0 4:32.0'
```

Is that adequate?

Comment: Gee, it took me some head-scratching to get this! You're using a  back-reference, ``\1``, and just append ``.0``.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d)( |$)', r'\1.0\2', ':: 1:62 2:31 :: 3:4 4:32')
':: 1:62.0 2:31.0 :: 3:4.0 4:32.0'
```